# How can I make a form update the text on the main form using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, constructor

I'm trying to use update the text in H1 with someone's name. I'm using a Class Constructor.
I tried using `document.forms["myform"]["inputbox"].value;`  to acess the text that above the form. How can I make the form update the update text?

```
     var formInput = document.forms["myform"]["inputbox"].value;
     var output = document.getElementById("upDateText");
     class Message {
      constructor(name, style, alignment, type) {
        this.name = formInput;
        this.text = document.innerText = type;
      }
      say() {
        `hi my name is ${this.name}`;
      }
    }
     function text() {
     var counter = 0;
      counter++;
      if (counter == 0) {
        //this creates a new message after send button is clicked
        var myMessage = new Message();
    }
```

*HTML*

```
        <div>
          <h1 id="upDateText">Hi there what is your Name!</h1>
        </div>
        <form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="GET">
          <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="formInput" />
          <button onclick="text()" id="button">
            send
          </button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a `form` you could use its awesome qualities. Forms holds a reference to every `input`, `textarea` or `select` element that is in it. This also means that you can access all the values of those elements through the `form`.

Instead of listening for a click, listen for `submit`. Normally the form would send your data to an endpoint but you can overwrite this with JavaScript using [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

When submitting the form you can use [`FormData API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to extract all the `name` and `value` values from all the `input` (and the others) elements in the form.

In your `class` you're doing a funny thing by defining *parameters* in the `constructor` but never using them. Either use them or remove them. Same goes for referencing to `formInput` inside the constructor. If `formInput` is not defined, your code would fail.

Your `say` method simply has a string in it. This would result in an error. Either assign the string to a variable like `` let sentence = `hi my name is ${this.name}`; `` or return it.

Check out the example below to see it all coming together. Let me know if you have any questions or if I have been unclear.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("upDateText");
const form = document.getElementById('myform');

class Message {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  say() {
    return `hi my name is ${this.name}`;
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const name = formData.get('inputbox');
  const message = new Message(name);
  const sentence = message.say();
  output.textContent = sentence;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="upDateText">Hi there what is your Name!</h1>
</div>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="formInput" />
  <button id="button">send</button>
</form>
```

If the `FormData API` is hard to grasp, then you could always make it a little bit simpler, although less dynamic. In the `submit` listener get the `value` from the `formInput` element and use that to create your `Message` instance.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("upDateText");
const formInput = document.getElementById('formInput');
const form = document.getElementById('myform');

class Message {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  say() {
    return `hi my name is ${this.name}`;
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  const name = formInput.value;
  const message = new Message(name);
  const sentence = message.say();
  output.textContent = sentence;
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="upDateText">Hi there what is your Name!</h1>
</div>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="formInput" />
  <button id="button">send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: how did you use Form API?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you be more specific?

Comment: when you are referring to formData API what are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to `const formData = new FormData(event.target); const name = formData.get('inputbox');` in my example. `event.target` is the current form that is submitted. That form is then used in the `FormData` constructor to create a new `FormData` instance. This instance holds all `input` names and values in your form.

Comment: But I still don't know what formData API will it contain my fromdata do I need to call it like a normal API?

Comment: Ah, the FormData API is a native interface available in your browser, not an endpoint to download from. The API part means, in laymen terms, a tool to get something done. In this case you do `var formData = new FormData();` anywhere in your code, and you are using the API. If you use a `form` element in combination with `FormData`, like `new FormData(form)`, then the API will get all values from that form and store it in an object. Otherwise you would have to select each `input` element to get each value. This *tool* makes it a lot simpler. I hope that makes sense.